# Join without from dual in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following statement that I would like to convert from Oracle SQL to SQL Server. I have trouble in the second query (B) where I `INNER JOIN`.

Can I `INNER JOIN` without a `FROM` clause or without creating the `Dual` table in SQL Server?

```
With A as (
select cast('A' as varchar(129)) J_N
,cast('Bit' as varchar(255)) J_V
from dual
)
, B as (
select 1 as RB
,getdate() as J_S_T
,cast('J_S' as varchar(255)) as [mess]
,A.J_N as J_N
from dual
inner join A on 1=1

union all

select 2 as RB
, getdate() as J_S_T
,cast('J_V' as varchar(255)) || A.J_V as [mess]
,A.J_N as J_N
from dual
inner join A on 1=1
```

Comment: *"Can I `INNER JOIN` without a `FROM` clause"* To perform a `JOIN` you **need** a `FROM`. That isn't specific to SQL Server, that's just part of SQL. You can't return data from a table without a `FROM`. Do you actually mean can you perform an `INNER JOIN` with out an `ON`? If so, then no, you need something to "join on". You, however, have `ON 1=1` which is some what nonsensical. It's seems like what you are actually after is a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: `||` is not valid there as a string concatenation

Comment: The OP is coming from Oracle, @MarkSchultheiss , where `||` is the concatenation operator. It seems that the above isn't their attempt at T-SQL, but their PL\SQL.

Comment: `from dual` is an oracle thing. In SQL Server you can just do `select 1 as column1, 'abc' as col2` without a `from` clause at all.

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server just omit `dual`.  It's a single-row table in Oracle, and doesnt't change the number of rows when you cross-join it. EG:

```
select 1 as RB
,getdate() as J_S_T
,cast('J_S' as varchar(255)) as [mess]
,A.J_N as J_N
from A
```

Or if you have lots of queries that use `dual` and want to keep using it, you can create one in SQL Server:

```
create table DUAL 
(
  DUMMY varchar(1) primary key
    check (DUMMY = 'X')
)

insert into DUAL(DUMMY) values ('X')
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, `inner join ... on 1=1` is a `cross join` and should be written as such. No matter whether Oracle or SQL Server.

Then, selecting from dual in order to cross join with a table makes little sense. You can just select the values.

```
select * from mytable cross join (select 1 as colx from dual)
```

for instance is nothing else than

```
select mytable.*, 1 as colx from mytable
```

In your case you don't even select from any table. It's all dual. It's a mere

```
SELECT 1 AS rb, GETDATE() AS j_s_t, CAST('J_S' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS mess, CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(129)) AS j_n
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS rb, GETDATE() AS j_s_t, CAST('J_VBit' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS mess, CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(129)) AS j_n;
```

And if this is not part of a `CREATE TABLE xxx AS` statement, you may not even need the casts, which would get the query still more readable:

```
SELECT 1 AS rb, GETDATE() AS j_s_t, 'J_S' AS mess, 'A' AS j_n
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS rb, GETDATE() AS j_s_t, 'J_VBit' AS mess, 'A' AS j_n;
```